# Scale image from all sides

Tags: html, css, image, scale, display

this might be a dumb problem but I've been struggling for hours on this...

I need to scale up an image on hover from all sides.
Currently my image is scaling from only the right side.

I use bootstrap.

**Image before scaling :**
[image: Image before scaling]

**Image scaled :**
[image: Image scaled]

I think it's a display problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Bonus problem :
I would like to have a little box fixed to the bottom of the image showing up when hovered, a bit like netflix. Any idea?

Many thanks

```css
.grid{
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  }
.mini{
  height: 150px ;
  justify-content: flex-center;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.a{
  margin: 25px;
  align-items: center;  
  display: flex;
 }
 .mini:hover{
  height: 250px;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid grid">
   <div class="row mt-5 r">
     <div class="col a r"><img src="images/1.jpg" class="mini"></div>
     <div class="col a r"><img src="images/2.jpg" class="mini"></div>
     <div class="col a r"><img src="images/3.jpg" class="mini"></div>
     <div class="col a r"><img src="images/4.jpg" class="mini"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don’t manipulate the height, use a `scale` transformation instead, and set `transform-origin: center`

Comment: _“Bonus problem : I would like to have a little box fixed to the bottom of the image showing up when hovered, a bit like netflix. Any idea?”_ - put the box where you need it (use case for absolute positioning), and then only make it visible when the box gets hovered. Keywords to read up on if you are not familiar with them: child combinator, descendant combinator.

Comment: use transform scale on hover instead of  give height to img on hover & use "oveflow hidden" in image parent tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may this can help in scale images issue

```css
.wrapper-content {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1160px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper-image img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.wrapper-image{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper-image:hover img {
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   
    <div class="wrapper-content">
   
        <div class="wrapper-image">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1352&amp;q=80">
        </div>
      

      </div>
      
    </div>
```